# Make top image stay in position when main image resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main image and little callout buttons on top of the main image.  I'm trying to get the callout buttons to stay in position when the screen size changes while the main image size resizes with `max-width` and `background-size: contain`, but right now, the callout button's position changes.

Here is the CSS:

```
.main_image
{
   background: red;
   height: 400px;
   background-size: contain;
   position: relative;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.callouts
{
   background-image: url(http://www.autotintspecialist.com/zoomButton_moused.png);
   height: 70px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 30px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 70px;
   right: 180px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
   <img class="main_image" src="http://autotintspecialist.com/sOff_off.jpg">
</div>
<div class="callouts"></div>
```

Here is the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nem2C/

As you resize the image, the callout button changes position, but I need it to stay where it's at when the image resizes.

is there a jquery solution or a javascript solution to this as well?

Comment: Your _callout_ is staying put.  Right where you told it to.  This "moving" is only due to the _main image_ resizing, so you won't get a perfect solution.  Did you try pixels instead of percentages?  Something like `top: 38%; left: 31%;`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Thats brilliant!  Thank you.......wish we can change this to the answer so i can vote you up

Comment: @RickyAhn I changed my comment to [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18086623/578288).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix this. I didn’t finish, but I got closer to the solution.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/wqEan/). I put `div.callouts` inside the `div` with the image and positioned it relative to that with percentage values.

```html
<div class="image_wrapper">
    <img class="main_image" src="http://autotintspecialist.com/sOff_off.jpg">
    <div class="callouts"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.image_wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.callouts{
    top: 15.5%;
    right: 24.1%;
}
```

To calculate the correct percentage value from, for example, the top, use the formula `(image_height_in_pixels / pixels_from_the_top) * 100`.

The problem with what I have now is that the callout x-position doesn’t scale with the width properly for some reason.